# How to silent cvxopt solver [Python]?

Tags: python, module, silent, cvxopt

Whenever I run Python cvsopt solver in terminal, it will print:

```
     pcost       dcost       gap    pres   dres
 0: -8.0742e+00 -7.3715e+00  3e+03  5e+01  4e-15
 1: -6.6241e-01 -7.2834e+00  7e+01  1e+00  3e-15
......
Optimal solution found.
```

Can I silent this message? Thank you!

Comment: You can always pipe the output to /dev/null if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 19):

Just add the following line before calling the solvers:

```py
solvers.options['show_progress'] = False
```

See [CVXOPT User Group - How to silence the cvxopt solver](https://groups.google.com/g/cvxopt/c/0jFVcWsjW8o).

Comment: your answer should follow brief explanation for a better understanding for the others

Answer (score 7):

You may need to pass options specific to the particular solver you're using. For example, to silent the cvxopt LP solver output for GLPK: add the option

```
options={'glpk':{'msg_lev':'GLP_MSG_OFF'}}
```

E.g. `result = cvxopt.solvers.lp(c, G, h, A, b, solver='glpk', options={'glpk':{'msg_lev':'GLP_MSG_OFF'}})`. You may be better off using a less radical reduction of output, cf. http://glpk-java.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/gnu/glpk/GLPKConstants.html for all allowed message levels.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I even combined this answer with sjm 's answer and it still prints out everything.

Comment: @loganjones16 `solvers.lp(c, A, b, options={'show_progress': False})` works for me. But specifying the solver `solver='glpk'` messes it up for some reason.